# using matrix 3d css transformations and javascript

Tags: jquery, css, matrix, 3d, scale

Hi i've been stuck for a while trying to reproduce the zooming and transitionary effects achieved here: http://f-k-a-twigs.tumblr.com/

I was wondering if anyone knew how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Which effect exactly? http://bouncejs.com/ is a solid generator that uses matrix3d. You can piece together your own animations and export the CSS from there.

Edit: Just noticed the scrolling effects you were talking about. If you're using jQuery you can hook your animations to the .scroll() event. See here: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! im referring to how the image (or video) fades out as another element is brought into frame by the zoom. How would i go about putting the elements in what appears to be a pseudo 3d space?